# How to add image to bitmap of ListView in RAD studio

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, rad

I took one ListView. I have change the itemAppearance to DynamicAppearance.
This listview contains one bitmap as member. Now I want to populate the list by C++ code. There are 2 members in listview Text & Image(MyImage). I am able to assign the value to Text by C++ and now i am trying to assign the images to bitmap image of listview. but i am unable to assign the image to listview.
Below is the code i have written:

```
 __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
: TForm(Owner)
```

{

ListView1->BeginUpdate();

```
try{
for(int i = 0; i<=10; i++)
{
    TListViewItem* item = ListView1->Items->Add();
    TListItemText *Txt = (TListItemText*)item->Objects->FindObject("Text1");
    Txt->Text = "Sarthak Mirajkar";
    TListItemImage* img = (TListItemImage*)item->Objects->FindObject("MyImage");

    img->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("Images\\123.bmp");

}
}
catch(...)
{}

ListView1->EndUpdate();
```

}

This code does not give compiler error but its not working.
I have tried to gave the path many ways in the statement img->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("Images\123.bmp"); but nothing works.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good that you used the firemonkey tag. At first, I didn't know what you meant. The VCL TListView works differently and, IIRC, uses a TImageList to hold the images.

Comment: Hmmm.. AFAICT, a TListViewItem has an ImageIndex property. So try the following: put your images in a TImageList, link it to the TListView and set the ImageIndex of the TListViewItem to the index of the image in the ImageList. It would not surprise me if the ListView had several links to image lists, for different sizes.

Comment: Also, take a look here: http://www.fmxdemos.com/ . Mainly in Delphi, but still easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Add a TImageList to your form and put your image(s) in it.  Then when you are populating your item you can assign it an image like this:

```
item->ImageIndex = 1;  // 1 = the image you want from the TImageList
```

Make sure you have set the ListView property "Images" to the name of your TImageList (probably ImageList1).

I hope I've interpreted your question correctly.  Good luck.

UPDATE:  I thought I'd add more complete code - see below.

```
// first add a header if you want too - not required
TListViewItem* itemHeader = ListView1->Items->Add();
ListView1->BeginUpdate();
itemHeader->Purpose = TListItemPurpose::Header;
itemHeader->Text = "My Header";  // 
ListView1->EndUpdate();

// now add your item
TListViewItem* item2Add = ListView1->Items->Add();
ListView1->BeginUpdate();
item2Add->Text = "My item text";
item2Add->ImageIndex = 1;  // set it's image to image 1 in the associated TImageList
ListView1->EndUpdate();
```

Hope this helps.

russ